# Eclipse ECF not working with our own XMPP server

Tags: linux, eclipse, frameworks, communication

We're using prosody with SSL/TLS. Chat works perfectly fine, but ECF just fails completely - nothing in the logs at all.

Sorry if I'm vague, but does anyone have a clue what's going on? Something else we might need to install to support ECF?